# Float inline top right

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to get an image to stay in the upper right corner when clicked, but let other elements flow around it?

```
img.selected{
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vL9RN/3/

When you click on the images towards the right of the list, they float right but don't stay on the top of the page, but instead flows under other images. Is there any way to do this with css?

Comment: So, do you always want the selected image to be at the top and all the thumbnails to be underneath?

Comment: Here is a partialy working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vuvz8/

Comment: @Gimmy I don't see any difference from yours to mine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img.selected{
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the thumbnails end up overlaid on the image. I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem. Check this out :) http://jsfiddle.net/vL9RN/4/

Sorry I used JQuery though since i am not that versed with javascript without using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('img').eq(0).addClass('selected');

    $('img').not('selected').click(function(){
        $('img.selected').insertBefore($('img').eq($(this).index())).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).insertBefore($('img').eq(0)).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work with my setup, I get my image list from a php script using ajax and can't get scripts to run without using "onclick". I know there are ways to fix this but they're beyond my understanding. Can this script be adapted to run as an onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `float: left;` to your `img` css.

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/vL9RN/5/)

An alternative approach would be,

have all your thumbnails in a `<div>`, and have the "selected" img as a separate `<img />` in another `<div>`. Then, all you'd need to do `onClick` is change the `src` property of the "selected" img.